# Nuxt Universal deploy - Server Call Timeout

Tags: nginx, deployment, nuxt.js, digital-ocean, universal

i've an issue with my NuxtJs deployment. I'm trying to do this with DigitalOcean Droplet and nginx. I'm using Nginx with reverse proxy with the configuration below.

```
server {
   listen          80;             # the port nginx is listening on
   server_name     reepen.gg;    # setup your domain here

   gzip            on;
   gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css application/javascript;
   gzip_min_length 1000;

,  location / {
      expires $expires;

      proxy_redirect                      off;
      proxy_set_header Host               $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
      proxy_read_timeout          1m;
      proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
      proxy_pass                          http://localhost:3000; # set the address of the Node.js instance here
   }
}
```

When i try `curl http://localhost:80`, the response is the index html code of my Nuxt application. But when i try to call my droplet outside with his ip address or domain name, i've `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. I don't know why my droplet ip address are not connected with my http://localhost:80

To configure my droplet i used this tutorial (i've set firewall as in doc) https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-18-04

And i've tryed this tutorial to deploy my app https://medium.com/codeartisan/how-to-run-nuxt-js-on-digitalocean-159fc558d2ab

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my ufw firewall set in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-18-04

When i disabled it all works fine !